# Export 3D file from VTK to VMTK (The Vascular Modeling Toolkit) c++

Tags: vtk, voxel, medical

I am working on extracting blood vessel from brain in 3D ( Voxel ) and I would like to process the model in VMTK. I saw the example of VMTK application uses VTP (VT polygon) or STL files as an input for processing. I would like to ask which is the best way to send file between VTK and VMTK back and forth.

For VTK, I am not sure which class should I export as VTP to VMTK program. I just ImageReader to read a sequence of images and reconstruct using vtkFixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper and vtkVolume. Should I convert the voxel to polygon first and then feed to vmtk to find centerlines? or the voxel can be save to VTP or STL format directly.